# How to line left justify label and entry boxes in Tkinter grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm still pretty new to Tkinter and Classes, but I am trying to left justify labels and entry boxes each within their own column of a Tkinter grid. I am using `Justify=LEFT`, but it seems to have no impact as the labels look centered and the entry boxes start where the label ends.

```
from Tkinter import *

class LabeledEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kargs):
        text = kargs.pop("text")
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text=text, justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=0)
        Entry(self, justify=LEFT, *args, **kargs).grid(column=1, row=0)

class User_Input:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        fields = ['Text Label 1', 'This is the text Label 2']
        GUIFrame =Frame(parent)
        GUIFrame.pack(expand=True, anchor=NW)
        parent.minsize(width=350, height=325)
        field_index = 1
        for field in fields:
            self.field = LabeledEntry(GUIFrame, text=field)
            self.field.grid(column=0, row=field_index)
            field_index += 1
        self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='exit', command= parent.quit)
        self.Button2.place(x=25, y=300)

root = Tk()

MainFrame =User_Input(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that each time you create a new instance of `LabeledFrame`, you are placing both the `Entry` & `Label` within the same `Frame`.

The `grid` settings for this `Frame` are separate from any other `Frame`, so it is impossible for `LabeledFrame`s to align columns as they do not have the same values for column widths.

Normally to accomplish what you are after you would simply put `sticky = W` in the `grid` options for the `Entry` widget to left-justify the contents of the cell. However, this will only work for each individual `Frame`, leaving the contents of each separate `LabeledFrame` out of alignment.

Easiest way to fix this without changing much code:

You'll want to add a line to your `for` loop. If you specify a large minimum-width of the column that `self.field`'s `Frame` is inserted into, you can be sure that things will align how you want them to. I've also added config options to the `grid` calls within the `LabeledEntry` class: `sticky = W` for the `Label` & `sticky = E` for the `Entry`.

Try this out and see if it solves your problem. If you would like the column to take less space simply reduce `minsize`.

```
from Tkinter import *

class LabeledEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kargs):
        text = kargs.pop("text")
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text=text, justify=LEFT).grid(sticky = W, column=0,row=0)
        Entry(self, *args, **kargs).grid(sticky = E, column=1, row=0)

class User_Input:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        fields = ['Text Label 1', 'This is the text Label 2']
        GUIFrame =Frame(parent)
        GUIFrame.pack(expand=True, anchor=NW)
        parent.minsize(width=350, height=325)
        field_index = 1
        for field in fields:
            self.field = LabeledEntry(GUIFrame, text=field)
            self.field.grid(column=0, row=field_index)
            self.field.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, minsize = 150)
            field_index += 1
        self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='exit', command= parent.quit)
        self.Button2.place(x=25, y=300)

root = Tk()

MainFrame =User_Input(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 16):

I have had success using both justify and anchor:

```
Label(self, text=text, justify="left", anchor="w").grid(sticky = W, column=0,row=0)
```

Comment: Note that I had to enclose LEFT in quotes and use lower case (justify="left")

Comment: @Matthew Whether `LEFT` works depends on the import statements for tkinter. it may also be `tk.LEFT` or `tkinter.LEFT`. So using the value of the constant here makes sense.