# Align text to left with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'd like to align my text to the left but `anchor='w'` does not seem to work... 
Any tips ?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
window = Tk()

lab = Label(window, text = 'hey', anchor='w')
lab2 = Label(window, text='hellooooooo', anchor='w')

lab.grid(column=0, row=0)
lab2.grid(column=0, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

[tkinter window picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6YBq.png)

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140590/how-to-line-left-justify-label-and-entry-boxes-in-tkinter-grid)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using anchor property, use sticky property of grid layout. The modified code with sticky will be as follow.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
window = Tk()

lab = Label(window, text = 'hey')
lab2 = Label(window, text='hellooooooo')

lab.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
lab2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')
window.mainloop()
```

Hope this code will do what you want.

Comment: (I just had to use ```sticky='w'``` instead since "W is not defined").

Answer (score 0):

this ist the solution
tk.Label(anchor="w", justify="left")

so change your sample to this

```
lab = Label(window, text = 'hey', anchor='w', justify="left")
lab2 = Label(window, text='hellooooooo', anchor='w', justify="left")
```